# How do you query for records with no associated record (linked via join table)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have table A and table B, and a join table we'll call C.

A has many B through C.

B has many A through C.

```
C table structure:
a_id
b_id
```

I'm trying to find As which have zero associated Bs.

Can this be done using joins?

Currently I'm doing it like this:

```
as_with_no_bs = A.select{|a| a.bs.empty?}
```

But that's probably much less efficient than using joins.

Answer (score 0):

**Assumptions:**

- a_id and b_id are required for a c record to exist
- A table name is "as"
- A has a relation to C as `has_many :cs`
- C table name is "cs"

**(Some) Available Solutions:**

Rails < 4

```
# we could use Arel to make this more "code based" but for the sake of example
A.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN cs on cs.a_id = as.id")
  .where(cs: {id: nil})
```

Rails 4 +

```
A.where.not(id: C.select(:a_id))
```

Rails 5+

```
A.left_joins(:cs).where(cs: {id: nil})
```

Rails 6.1+

```
A.where.missing(:cs)
```

Comment: There are alternate solutions or similar and differing variations of the above that would also be effective as query based solutions